# Good strategy for creating standalone controls Direct2D

Tags: c++, visual-c++, direct3d, direct2d

After spending a fair amount of time with Direct2D (1_1), I am looking for information on creating standalone controls with Direct2D, primarily with hit-testing and abstracting layout.

Creating an entire scene is simple enough (special thanks to Kenny Kerr), however I have not found a good strategy for separating code into reusable UI components.

Ultimately I would also like to provide wrappers to these controls that would also be able to be used in WPF.  Thanks for your help.

[EDIT Feb 19 - 7AM]

Consider this very simple example:
The Render (or Draw) function renders a few rounded rect geometries, some of which overlap.  Now let's treat each of these rounded rects as an independent ui control.  So we abstract that rounded rect into its own class, provide a render function which has a parameter of a render target and a point at which to draw.  But there is a good deal more to consider.  The control shouldn't necessarily know where it is located.  And a generic hit testing strategy that our system can continue to build on would be important.

As @CodeAngry pointed out, properties like visible, enabled, zOrder, width, height, etc should be implemented.  But the layout system should be our starting point.

None of this is incredibly difficult, however I know this stuff is done everyday, and I was hoping to find some pattern or strategy to consider.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is a tricky question, and one that I'm not sure necessarily fits the typical question asked at stackoverflow.  This sounds more like a design question than a programming question.  Also I feel the question is awkwardly worded, so I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Comment: You don't mention it, but I assume you're using WPF for input processing? Never used that myself, only DirectInput or XInput in C++ Windows applications.  Not sure what you mean by standalone controls, can you clarify? Are you trying to create a portable abstract interface that can be used across different APIs/platforms?  Are you looking to abstract actions on top of abstracted control code? You need to figure out what exactly you want, and clarify.  Question is kind of vague.

Comment: *FUNNY*: I'm currently working on a Windowless UI for native C++ built on D2D1 and DW and WIC. I'm right at the same step as you are, making primary HWND render surface scrollable, interacting with controls and then creating custom controls. But I'm writing it for native C++, not with C# support.

Comment: And indeed, this is a question of design. First you need to think what defines and control, like ZOrder, size, scrollable area, origin point, enabled, visible and such. Then implement all this stuff. If you make them in HWNDs, you just need to manage scrolling and mouse/keyboard interaction. Hook the target window and get drawing...

Comment: @CodeAngry - Thanks for the note.  Primarily, I don't want to be concerned about managed code.  I think we may have similar goals.  I know this stuff is done every day, and thought there may be some good sources for information, or patterns which are popular.  I will edit my question to provide a very simple example.  Thanks again.

Comment: You say: *...properties like visible, enabled, zOrder, width, height, etc should be implemented. But the layout system should be our starting point...*. Actually, ZOrder tells you about overlapping and which control takes the actual hit when hit-testing. So it's not really optional.

Comment: @CodeAngry - Agreed.  zOrder must be done at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic hit testing can be done by doing something like this:

- each control should have a geometry of it's layout. Either a basic rectangle, ellipse, irregular shape. Then, the control manager does hit testing against them. Then orders possible matches by zorder
- just hit-tests against them in zorder to prevent the sorting step.

You should store control hierarchy zordered anyways, and this, by itself, skips the sorting.

Controls don't need to know about their location but NEED to know their sizes *(if rectangular)* and/or shapes. And the manager knows the location and a bounding rectangle. Combine these elements and you can the hit-test. First make sure the point falls in the bounding rectangle and only then hit-test against the control's geometry. Before hit-testing, update the HWND client point to the control client point by subtracting the control client offsets known by the control manager.

*That's how I'm (planning to) doing it. But I'm making it windowsless. If each control is in a child HWND of its own, life is so much easier!*

**PS**: You can mail me if you want to exchange ideas. You can find my email if you want to. ;)

Comment: I agree.  The control manager can also be abstracted for reuse on any container control.  I would also want this to be windowless, however wasn't sure how to separate render targets.  So if you make each bounding rect based on the control's desired width and height, and render in a child HWND, then the coords will start from top-left zero?  and the render function would look similar to the following:  void Render(HWND hwnd, RECT boundary); ?  Perhaps a base control that provides many of the other properties.  Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: It's C++. You have a base control with virtual functions. IF you want to avoid them, use C type callbacks stored in your DLL or library. The base control exposes some functions and the user can create new controls by using those predefined or creating new ones on top of the base control. Plus, you can use `PushAxisAlignedClip()` and `PopAxisAlignedClip()` to *(optionally)* clip control rendering to their bounding rects. --- The HWND needs to be a `ID2D1RenderTarget*` for controls. Don't keep creating a new one every time if windowless.

Comment: Ah!  That is some of what I was missing (PushAxisAlignedClip() and PopAxisAlignedClip()).  And ensuring the HWND implements ID2D1RenderTarget*.  Thanks again for your thoughts.